# Monodevelop custom syntax with highlighting

Tags: monodevelop, syntax-highlighting

How do I define a custom syntax with highlighting in Monodevelop (v3.0.6) for log files or JSON files. I only could find [Syntax_Mode_Definition](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Syntax_Mode_Definition) but it only shows very short snippets which are hard to understand.

Could somebody just show/link a short examlpe how such a file should look like and where it should be put?

Comment: The source is available so why not check existing syntax highlighting files?

Comment: I couldn't find any. Neither in the Installation directory, nor in the Appdata/Roaming, nor on github. They seem to be built-in in some way. I only found a file for custom color settings (like comments in green, code in black, keywords in blue...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find most of the built-in syntax highlighting definitions [here](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/SyntaxModes).

To add one, you would have to [write an addin](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Creating_a_Simple_Add-in) that [registers the definition](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/bfb4abf723eafca175fc1145433defeb76afc9b4/main/src/addins/TextTemplating/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating.addin.xml#L21) and [registers the mimetype](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/bfb4abf723eafca175fc1145433defeb76afc9b4/main/src/addins/TextTemplating/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating.addin.xml#L25).

Comment: so I can't just put my syntaxmode file in a folder to use it :( But I just noticed that I can get highlighting for JSON files by naming them *.json Thank you